# Sign of exchange integral in GKA (superexchange) rules

Tags: condensed-matter, ferromagnetism, exchange-interaction

I was reading about the super-exchange mechanism that leads to magnetic order (Antiferromagnetic or Ferromagnetic) in insulating solids [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0022369759900617). Kanamori breaks down the mechanisms in several specific cases - Section 2 of the paper deals with the superexchange interaction between octahedrally coordinated cations at a 180$^o$ angle. He goes on to mention that the net superexchange interaction is just the product of the signs of the bond and the exchange integral. However, I can't seem to reconcile this sign of exchange integral in the many cases mentioned in the paper.

For example, let us take the example of interaction between cations with a d3 valence configuration, mediated by a ligand in the center. Kanamori goes on to say that the exchange integral between d-p$\pi$ in this case carries a negative sign, but I don't understand why. In general, I don't understand how the sign of the exchange integral is inferred. I understand in some cases, you cannot definitively infer the sign of the exchange integral, but I want to reconcile the definitive cases.